# PDF Press and generated PDF header/footer part

Tags: add-on, pdf-press

I have working PDF Press generator which uses save_to_pdf method because I need to have a name of generated PDF based on an entry title.

Based on DOMPDF FAQ https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ I can add footer/header image to generated PDF, but I'm stuck on which PDF Press file do I need to edit to have accomplish that part?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple back and forth with the add-on developer (more here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/pdf-press/viewthread/12738) I have got accomplished the goal using a CSS trick from here http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=b264f350e6967875987e14faa0c751f0

Template example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    @page { margin: 180px 50px; }
    #header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: orange; text-align: center; }
    #footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: lightblue; }
    #footer .page:after { content: counter(page, upper-roman); }
  </style>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Widgets Express</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p class="page">Page </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>the first page</p>
    <p style="page-break-before: always;">the second page</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```